# How to sort Google Sheets using a criterion

Tags: google-sheets-query

## Background/Business Case

I'm a recruiter who uses spreadsheets to organize the work I've done with candidates with respect to a certain job vacancy.

Like [streak](https://www.streak.com/), I would like to have a pipeline that shows how my candidates are going through a certain progression or pipeline. I've put the different statuses of the pipeline here:

[image]

In the following figure, you can see that I've entered my candidates data, and I've put conditional formatting so that they are color depending on the status they're in:
[image]

## Question

Notice how in this screenshot, i sorted the candidates according to the status *alphabetically*:

[image]
However, i want it sorted according to the same order available in the pipeline status depicted above, ie according to this order:
- initial contact
- interested
- discussing
- ..

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have the data in `Sheet1` and the pipeline list in `Sheet2`, you can copy the data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet3`. Do the editing in `Sheet1`, and any other sorting, such as by country, name, source, etc. and keep `Sheet3` as an automatically updated, and sorted view based on the pipeline.

- Create `Sheet3` with the needed column headings to match those on `Sheet1`.
- In `Sheet3` cell `A2` enter the formula: `=ArrayFormula(sort(Sheet1!A2:E,match(left(Sheet1!D2:D,6),left(Sheet2!A1:A10,6),0),1))`

You will need to adjust the following:

- range <kbd>`A2:E`</kbd> by replacing <kbd>`E`</kbd> with your last column
- range <kbd>`D2:D`</kbd> by replacing <kbd>`D`</kbd> with the column that actually has the status you are sorting on
- the <kbd>`6`</kbd> in both `left` functions with the minimum number of characters to make each item in the pipeline unique.
- the names of `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` if you have renamed the sheets to something more meaningful (as you probably should)

Adding and rearranging the items in the pipeline, as well as adding and editing rows on the main sheet, and inserting columns on the main sheet, are automatically accommodated by Google Sheets, so that you don't have to reformulate the equation for changes that you make in the pipeline, or for new entries in the data. (One exception to this: if you add a column to `Sheet1` you will need to change the header row in `Sheet3` to match.)

<sup>**Note:**</sup>
IMHO, as complex as this seems to be getting, you probably ought to look into switching to a database for this instead of a spreadsheet.

Comment: hey man great answer.. i wanted to follow the logic of your equation though and left you a question on the other answer you provided [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78070/how-to-sort-a-google-sheets-query-by-a-custom-ordering#comment94448_78087) please take a look

Comment: @abbood That other answer isn't mine, so I was never notified of the comment. But, in that answer, what's happening is that the `{"sop";"con";"ten";"bas"}` portion is creating a "temporary" range to match against using the first 3 characters of the voice range. A similar approach could have been done here, rather than the range on the other sheet. That, however would either lock you into only those stages in the pipeline, or be tricky to edit as stages are added. This version scales better, that one don't, and don't need to since choir parts have been fixed for generations now.

Comment: [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/109207/how-to-sort-incrementally) is a similar other question